# Using Bootstrap styles with partials in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I style a partial in Rails? I'm using the Bootstrap-SASS gem and have a universal partial for a navbar. I just need to change the design of the navbar and can't seem to get my scss to work. I feel like this should be super simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partials act like any other HTML on the site. It sounds to me like you want to simple label your navbar with your own custom selector so you can apply styles to it directly:

```
<nav id="my_navbar" class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
```

Then in your CSS:

```
#nav {
   /* Whatever styles you want to add*/
}
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully! It's been a while since I've had to do any site design. Really appreciate the help!